# SurveyMonkey API send response of Survey Back to Zendesk Ticket

Tags: surveymonkey, zendesk

I am trying to verify that via the SurveyMonkey API I can send the response(s) from a survey back into Zendesk data.  I want to be able to attach the response(s) from a survey, back to the ticket that send the survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I do not know about Survey Monkey but I know that you can do it with Examinare Survey API. developer.examinare.com and they also have an developer account that you can use to try.

If you message them by the support email I am sure they can give a better step to step directions but what you basically do is to activate the Zendesk integration and then add the redirect url to an external PHP Script and then take the ContactID, Inforeg (Serialnumber for the survey vote) and then parse it into the custom fields.

I know that Examinare has customers using Zendesk and their solution so try that out.

Comment: That is exactly the company I am working with currently.  They have been awesome and we almost have the code to work an input the data to ZD.